# A group which multiplies input by 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want a group in $Z$ which multiplies the input by 2.

I'm considering a group in $Z$ with the operator $2a$ where $a \in Z$ but I'm a bit rusty in abstract algebra. Can I use such an operator?

Comment: Is $Z$ the integers? What do you mean by operator? A homomorphism?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the subgroup $2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Would a group in $2Z$ with the operator $+$ deliver a group which multiplies any two numbers plus'd by 2? 

Example: 2+4 = 16

Is this correct?

Comment: You are trying to find a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$.  But in doing so you will inherit the operation $+$ from $\mathbb Z$.  So this is not possible...unless you want to make $\mathbb Z$ a group under some other definition of $+$ first.

Comment: Like all of us when we’re just learning something or when we’ve been away from it for a long time, your ideas are confused and difficult to penetrate. Generally speaking, a group doesn’t *do* anything, it just sits there lookin’ pretty. So your wording “a group … which multiplies” throws most of us off very seriously. I guess you might spend some time thinking things through more clearly, and maybe rewrite your question.

Answer (score 0):

In groups the operator acts on an ordered pair not on a single unit. For example the group of integers under addition, you need to give it an ordered pair $(a,b)$ and the addition gives you the number $a+b$. for example, the group of the non-zero integers under multiplication sends the pair $(2,a)$ to the number $2a$. This particular group is commutative, this means the pairs $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are always sent to the same thing (give the same output). Commutative groups are also called abelian groups.

Comment: Hmm so the group under non-zero integers with the multiplication operator on (2,a) is essentially a group which multiplies any $a$ in the set of the group by 2?

Can I define the group as such?

Comment: No you must have an operation defined on all pairs of nonzero integers.

Comment: Unfortunate. Thank you.

Comment: In a group the operator is a binary operator, meaning you need to give it an input consisting of two numbers. I think what you want is unary operator, however these don't give you a group.